# Reading Temperature from Intel Chipset

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I want to read the temperature of my CPU (Intel 6 Series Chipset) and took a look in the chipset datasheet (which I found [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/6-chipset-c200-chipset-datasheet.html)).

On page 857 it is stated:

> TSTR—Thermal Sensor Thermometer Read Register
>
> Offset Address: TBARB+03h
>
> Attribute: RO
>
> Default Value: FFh
>
> Size: 8 bit
>
> Description: Thermometer Reading (TR)— RO. Value corresponds to the thermal sensor
> temperature. This register has a straight binary encoding that ranges from 0 to FFh.
> The value in this field is valid only if the TR value is between 00h and 7Fh.

I think I am on the right track but now I am stuck at finding out how to access the register. I have written a little assembler in gnu AS x86 but I am new to Intel assembly. Can someone point me in the right direction? What's my next step? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your assembly program?

Comment: Probably, you should read PCI Device 31 Fn 6, get the address of memory block assigned for thermal registers and read corresponding memory location.